# Sort list of object taking priority number(weight) for each property in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list as declare below and I want to sort the list basing on `name` property having weight to each name.This may be very simple but pardon me I am stuck here to do it in best way.

```
public class A
{
    public float x;
    public string name;

public A(float x, string name)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.name = name;
}

List<A> allAs = new List<A>();

allAs.Add(new A(10, "CAR"));
allAs.Add(new A(22, "BUS"));
allAs.Add(new A(100, "TRAIN"));
allAs.Add(new A(0, "HYPERLOOP"));
```

Example:

```
name - weight
HYPERLOOP- 1,
TRAIN - 2,
CAR - 3,
BUS - 4
```

The sorted list should print as below:

```
name - x
HYPERLOOP- 0,
TRAIN - 100,
CAR - 10,
BUS - 22
```

Comment: Where are those "weight"s stored?

Comment: currently no where , thinking of storing them as a dict

Comment: if you can use `linq` do something like this: `List<SomeClass> b = a.OrderBy(x => x.x).ThenBy(x => x.y).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order by a `name/weight`-Dictionary

```
List<A> allAs = new List<A>();
allAs.Add(new A(10, "CAR"));
allAs.Add(new A(22, "BUS"));
allAs.Add(new A(100, "TRAIN"));
allAs.Add(new A(0, "HYPERLOOP"));

Dictionary<string, int> nameweight = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
{
    { "HYPERLOOP", 1 }, 
    { "TRAIN", 2 }, 
    { "CAR", 3 }, 
    { "BUS", 4 }
};
allAs = allAs.OrderBy(x => nameweight[x.name]).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0uXNU4

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add another field to your A class, as you don't seem to be sorting on either Name or X.  For example:

```
    public class A
{
    public float x;
    public string name;
    public int weight;

public A(float x, string name, int weight)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
}

List<A> allAs = new List<A>();

allAs.Add(new A(10, "CAR", 3));
allAs.Add(new A(22, "BUS", 4));
allAs.Add(new A(100, "TRAIN", 2));
allAs.Add(new A(0, "HYPERLOOP", 1));
```

Then use a bit of linq to sort your list:

```
var sortedList = AllAs.OrderBy(a => a.weight).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SortedDictionary

```
        SortedDictionary<int, A> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, A>()
        {
            {1, new A(0, "HYPERLOOP")},
            {2, new A(100, "TRAIN")}
            \\...
        };
```